# LuaJIT FFI crashes when freeing memory

Tags: c++, lua, free, ffi, luajit

I create a cdata object:

```
session = ffi.new("GAMESession*[1]", {})
```

I pass it in my C++ function:

```
GAMEDLL.GAME_close(session[0])
```

That C++ function has this code:

```
GAMEErrorCode
GAME_close(GAMESession *match)
{
   if (!match) {
      return GAME_BAD_SESSION;
   }
   delete match;
   return GAME_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running this C++ function crashes my project, as does this:

```
ffi.C.free(session)
```

How can I free this memory properly?

extra note:

I must have `GAMESession*[1]` to pass the object properly to other C++ functions:

```
GAME_start(GAMESession **session)
```

Comment: You are writing C with fancy C++ keywords. This never works good.

Comment: Why do you thing you need to `delete` at all? See: [Garbage Collection of cdata Objects](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#gc)

Comment: @Drop this was an API not written by me and they suggest using GAME_close to free the memory. So you are saying doing something like `session[0] = nil` `session=nil` will accomplish the same thing as `delete` would (just with the gc rather than right away)?

Comment: Did you use something like `GAME_open` to create the memory? With the code you've shown, it looks like you're trying to close a null pointer. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: the memory was created with `session = ffi.new("GAMESession*[1]", {})`, all C functions that manipulate the session object just have an out parameter requesting the object. (ex: `GAME_add_player(GAMESession *session, GAMEPlayer *player)`)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo also when I'm trying to close the memory it is not a null pointer. Data has been written to it in various C functions (it is constantly passed in as a parameter)

Comment: `ffi.new("GAMESession*[1]")` allocates a (one-element) array of pointers; the pointer initially don't point to anything (it's null). So how are you setting the pointer?

Comment: I assume `GAME_start(GAMESession **session)`. although it's not my API, I'm pretty sure I'm not passing null pointers into these C functions without major issues. The only issue I am having is with this particular function attempting to `delete` an object being pointed to by the sole parameter.

Comment: try to remove that empty table constructor from `ffi.new`. you might not want to initialize your pointer by ffi, but later by `GAME_start`…